# Javascript Letter Count

Tags: javascript, string, sorting

This code works but I don't understand why.Wouldn't it return the value of any word with more than 1 of a letter rather the letter that occurs the most at this point below.

```
if(count>1){
 return word;  
 }
```

Here's the full code

```
        function LetterCountI(str) { 
 var x=str.split(" ") 
   var count=0; 
   for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++)//getting the word
     var word=x[i]
     for(var j=0; j<word.length; j++)//getting the letter
      var letter=word[j]
       for(var k=0; k<word.length; k++)//comparing word
         if(j !== k) { /* verify that the letter being pased is not literally the same as in the higher for loop */
           if(letter===word[k]){
           count=count+1; 
              if(count>1){
               return word;  
           }
        }
     }   
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: Fun question that an experienced programmer might ask: what is a letter? Because "a" is a letter, but is  a letter? If it is, JavaScript string length will fail you, because  is one "character" but `"".length` is 2

Comment: In this case I mean /[a-zA-Z]/

Comment: > `the letter that occurs the most at this point below.` What do you mean when you say that?

Comment: in that case a followup question: if you don't understand what this code does, why use it? It would be more meaningful to say "I need to do ..., and I've written this code to do it: ..., but it doesn't seem to work because I see it do ... when I feed it ..., but I expect it to do ..., because of these lines here: ..., what am I doing wrong?"

Comment: Let's say for example the input is "aa bbb" ,why does it return "bbb" when count >1 for "aa"

Comment: -I need to sort a string and return the first word with the greatest number of repeated letters.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to return the first word that has repeated letters? The code doesn't make any attempt at finding the greatest number of repeated letters.

Answer (score 0):

The function doesn't loop all the words in the string and check for duplicate letters, it loops the words in the string, and then it loops the letters in the last word, then it checks for duplicates for that last letter in the last word.

Look at these lines:

```
for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++)//getting the word
  var word=x[i]
```

As there is no brackets for the code inside the loop, it's only the next statement that becomes the code in the loop. It's the same as:

```
for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {//getting the word
  var word=x[i]
}
```

This loop with go through the words in the string and put each one in the variable `word`, and when the loop ends the last word in the string is in the variable and the code can continue.

The next loop has the same error, so it will put each letter of the word in the variable `letter`, and continue when it has the last letter.

Adding some brackets to the loops will make the code work properly:

```js
function LetterCountI(str) { 
  var x = str.split(" ");
  var count = 0; 
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {//getting the word
    var word = x[i];
    for (var j=0; j<word.length; j++) {//getting the letter
      var letter = word[j];
      for (var k = 0; k < word.length; k++) {//comparing word
        if (j !== k) { /* verify that the letter being pased is not literally the same as in the higher for loop */
          if (letter === word[k]) {
            count = count + 1;
            if (count > 1) {
              return word;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

document.write(LetterCountI('What a cool boat'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function letterCount(word) {
    let letters = []
    if (word.length > 0) {
        for (x of word) {
            if(x == ' '){
                continue;
            }
            letters[x] = letters[x] ? letters[x] + 1 : 1
        }
    }
    return letters
}

console.log(letterCount('Letter Count For The Given Letter'))
```

Comment: Not sure what this code is supposed to do but, when I run it, it just prints an empty list: `[]`.